# how can i take a picture position like Instagram on flutter?

Tags: flutter, position, offset, scrollcontroller

[image]

post is not positioned under `AppBar` when I clicked on the picture except first. I want to make it like Instagram's function. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it work, do a logic to calculate the space and set the value directly.

If you use

```
scrollController.animateTo(180.0,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
```